# HTACCESS - regex / contains a capital letter?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all addresses which contain at least one capital character.

i.e:

dont rewrite - cities/nashville , but rewrite - cities/Nashville.

Comment: Can you show what you have at the moment?

Comment: RewriteRule ^jewelry-stores/nashville$ /jewelry/cities/nashville [L,R=301]

and i want it to apply also - Nashville

Comment: Do you think you might be looking at this wrong? Is it a necessity you redirect the URL or are you able to convert it to lowercase in your scripting language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [*NC* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to ignore the case for the pattern matching:

```
RewriteRule ^jewelry-stores/nashville$ /jewelry/cities/nashville [L,R=301,NE]
```

Otherwise, if you want to test for at least one capital letter, use `[A-Z]`:

```
RewriteRule ^jewelry-stores/([^A-Z]*[A-Z].*) /jewelry/cities/${tolower:$1} [L,R=301]
```

Additionally the [internal mapping function *tolower*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) is used to turn the matched string into lowercase. (Note that `RewriteMap` requires access to the server or virtual host configuration.)

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
RewriteRule ^citites/.*[A-Z].*$  /whatever [L,R=301]
```

should work as expected